# Electron set cookie with a url not working

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to build an electron + React app with login feature using a external login module.

I've loaded the login module inside a React page (currently on dev server http://localhost:8080) with a webview and it is a html hosted as https://login.example.com/login.html

And the login module requires a cookie which I have to set it in electron programmely.

So in `main.js` I tried this:

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: windowWidth,
    height: 480,
    titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      webviewTag:true,
    }
  });
mainWindow.webContents.session.cookies.set({ url: "https://login.example.com", key: key, value: value })

// I've also tried this
const { session } = require("electron")
session.defaultSession.cookies.set({ url: "https://login.example.com", key: key, value: value })
```

and the cookie was not succeessfully set.

However, it does work when I change the url to http://localhost:8080, but this won't work for the login module.

Is it still possible to set the cookie with a url different from the website that I'm loading with?

Comment: When in the lifecycle are you loading the webpage? Is it possible that the page gets loaded *before* you set the cookie?

Comment: I don't think any lifecycle will disable the cookie.set() method.    

I tried to deploy the react app instead of dev server. Then I setup electron to load the url of the html entry like "http:// mydomain.net/index .html", And the cookie was successfully set !  

I don't really understand why though.

Comment: That's not what I meant. When you set the cookie after the page is fully loaded, there's a change the webpage cannot read the cookie because it's not there (yet). Now, which version of Electron are you using? According to the [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/cookies#cookiessetdetails), `key` is not a valid parameter to `Cookies.set()`

Comment: You're right. I just checked my code and I was using the parameter `name` which is correct.
And as I said in the previous comment, it actually worked when I host the html properly instead of using `localhost`. This is quite confusing to me.